# Get substring between second and fourth slash

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a string that looks like this:

```
Y:\Data\apples\oranges\Scott\notes
```

I need a column that looks like this:

```
apples\oranges
```

This is what I have so far and it does not work:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    [Group], 
    CHARINDEX('\', [Group]) + 1, 
    LEN([Group]) - CHARINDEX('\', [Group]) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([Group]))
) from datamap.finaltest
```

The strings will not always have a finite amount of slashes.  For example you could have:

```
Y:\Data\Apples\bananas
Y:\Apples\Pears\oranges\peanuts
```

The data will always have:

```
drive letter + '\' + '1st level folder' + '\' + 'Second level folder'
```

It may have more than two levels though.

I have searched the forum but can't find anything specific.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to split this using one of `for xml` CSV to table splitters and select the 3d and 4th records? Just google tsql split CSV (hint: it can be any separator, even back slash).

Comment: is any of the path data a constant?  The key here is finding a pattern that fits all your potential data

Comment: @AlanWaage I just updated the question with the answer to that.  Always have drive letter and first two folder levels after that it could be more but never less.

Comment: If you are using sql server 2016, you can use string_split()

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I am using 2008 r2

Comment: what identifies the two folders you care about?  Is it always the 2nd and 3rd ones?

Comment: so, basically you need 2nd and 3rd folder names in the path? Is that what you mean by `between second and fourth slash`?  What if there are not enough folders in the path?

Comment: Yes I need the second and third folder.  There will ALWAYS be a drive letter first folder and second folder

Comment: it will never be a UNC path \\ instead of drive letter?

Comment: It will NEVER be unc.... they all start with Y:\Data\firstFolder\SecondFolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the best way, but this will get you there.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(255) = 'Y:\data\apples\oranges\Scott\notes'

SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(@string,LEN(@string)-CHARINDEX('\', @string, CHARINDEX('\', @string,1) + 1)),CHARINDEX('\', RIGHT(@string,LEN(@string)-CHARINDEX('\', @string, CHARINDEX('\', @string,1) + 1)), CHARINDEX('\',RIGHT(@string,LEN(@string)-CHARINDEX('\', @string, CHARINDEX('\', @string,1) + 1)),1)+1)-1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Gives me "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"

Comment: @VinnyGuitara it does work with the sample provided but if there is only three deep it would have to end with a \ or it would crash.

Comment: You were correct.  I updated to add the last slash!  Thanks

Comment: This solution is so dependent on the input;  If I supply input `Y:\data\apples`, it errors out

Answer (score 3):

A blatant approach by converting your input into XML and taking the values by node and re-concatenating the nodes you want in output

```
;WITH MyTempData
AS
(
    SELECT Convert(xml,'<n>'+Replace('Y:\Data\Apples','\','</n><n>')+'</n>') XMLString
)   
SELECT COALESCE(XMLString.value('(/n[3])', 'varchar(20)'),'') + '\' + 
       COALESCE(XMLString.value('(/n[4])', 'varchar(20)'),'') MyFinalOutput 
FROM MyTempData
```

Comment: Much more extensible!  I need between the 4th and 5th slashes, so this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using recursive `CHARINDEX`

```
declare @var varchar(4000) = 'Y:\Data\apples\oranges\Scott\notes'

declare @firstSlash int = (select CHARINDEX('\',@var,CHARINDEX('\',@var) + 1))

declare @fourthSlash int = (select CHARINDEX('\',@var,CHARINDEX('\',@var,CHARINDEX('\',@var,CHARINDEX('\',@var) + 1)+1)+1))

select SUBSTRING(@var,@firstSlash + 1,@fourthSlash - @firstSlash - 1)
```

Or, for your data table...

```
select SUBSTRING([Group],CHARINDEX('\',[Group],CHARINDEX('\',[Group]) + 1) + 1,CHARINDEX('\',[Group],CHARINDEX('\',[Group],CHARINDEX('\',[Group],CHARINDEX('\',[Group]) + 1)+1)+1) - CHARINDEX('\',[Group],CHARINDEX('\',[Group]) + 1) - 1)
```

Comment: good except in the case of Y:\Data\Apples\bananas because the last slash doesn't exist.  But to fix simple add a '\' at the end of each string and this function will work, it is easier than testing its existence first.

Comment: True @Matt i just assumed it would be there since OP said between 2nd and 4th slash, versus the 2nd and 3rd folder levels which may be what they were really after

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you need to do often, or is prone to changing, it may be beneficial to implement a function which will make your code more readable/maintainable:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@t, dbo.CHARINDEX2('\', @t, 2) + 1, dbo.CHARINDEX2('\', @t, 3));
```

Using this 'find nth occurence' function:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/30497/